# convert signed to unsigned value in C

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

I have got a negative value somehow which I need the equivalent positive value. I though adding MAX + 1 to that value, where MAX is the maximum value that can be represented with that many number of bits, we can resolve this issue. But it did not help. For example please look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int i;
    unsigned long long u;

    u = 0xffffffff38034080;

    u = 0xffffffffffffffff + u + 1;

    printf("0x%llx", u);
}
```

But this program returns the same negative number.

The output of the program is: `0xffffffff38034080`.  I would like it to be `0x0000000038034080`

Comment: `0xffffffff38034080` is a positive hex-number. What do you expect?

Comment: I want to convert 0xffffffff38034080 -> 0x0000000038034080

Comment: you just provoke an overflow and then you are at the exact same number. You could multiply by -1 or invert it with`~` and add 1 I think or use bitoperations like `&`

Comment: @mch fixed you may delete your comment. Thanks

Comment: You're working with some unusual definition of "equivalent" that you need to specify for this question to be answerable.

Comment: What do you mean by "negative number" and "positive number"? A bit more context of the application would be helpful. As you can see from the answers and comments, your question is not clear enough. Why is `u = (unsigned long long) -i;` not sufficient? Anyway, you never use, but declare, `i` in your code.

Comment: @Martin Nyolt  `-i` is UB should `i==LLONG_MIN`.  Better to use `u = -((unsigned long long) i);`

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is the 2's complement:

```
{
    unsigned long long u;

    u = 0xffffffff38034080;

    u = ~u + 1;

    printf("0x%llx", u);
}
```

Comment: Did you run this? The result is incorrect.  It outputs `0xc7fcbf80`.

Comment: The question included "I need the equivalent positive value". Negative values are processed like my example and the equivalent positive value of the bit pattern `0xffffffff38034080` is `0xc7fcbf80`. This result is correct. If something else was meant, the question is not precise enough. A conversion to `0x0000000038034080` as stated by the OP doesn't make any sense without further information. This is not how processors work.

Answer (score 1):

Check the top bit of the number.  If it's set, left shift by one to remove it and increment a bit counter.  Repeat until the top bit is not set.

Once you've done that, right shift by the counter.  This will shift in bits that are 0.

```
unsigned long long u;
int i,cnt = 0;

u = 0xffffffff38034080ULL;

while (((0x8000000000000000 & u) != 0) && (cnt < 64)) {
    u <<= 1;
    cnt++;
}
u >>= cnt;

printf("0x%llx", u);
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but can we have a macro or easier way to do this

Comment: @HimanshuDutta Just to clarify, are you sure this is what you want?  The value `0xffffffff38034080` interpreted as a negative number in decimal is `-3355230080`, while `0x38034080` as a positive number in decimal is `939737216`.  Conversely, `0xc7fcbf80` as a positive decimal is `3355230080`.

Comment: Yes. This is somewhat 2's complement is not working for me. So need to do this.

Comment: @HimanshuDutta Then the above is how you would do this.  You can put it into a function to make it easier to use.  Generally speaking, you shouldn't use a macro when it makes sense to use a function as macros can have subtle issues if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that If you want to be sure about how it works (I assume you are doing this as an exercise ) maybe you could just do someting like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    long long int i;
    unsigned long long u;
    long long negative_u;
    long long positive_u;

    u = 0xffffffff38034080;        
    memcpy(&negative_u, &u, sizeof(long long int));
    positive_u = negative_u * -1;      

    printf("0x%llx\n", u);
    printf("0x%llx\n", negative_u);
    printf("0x%llx\n", positive_u);
    return 0;
}
```

Now You should see the exact values of the bytes that you must change to achieve what you are looking for.

Regards!

Comment: the output is: `0xffffffff38034080
0xffffffff38034080
0xc7fcbf80`

Comment: Now for sure we can say Chris Tophski was totally right ;)

Comment: @HimanshuDutta I don't understand if you're satisfied or not. Chris Tophski is totally right, if you want to change sign you must calculate 2's complement and add 1. The result is just what you've seen (0xc7fcbf80) and it is evident in my code. Obviously you must consider 0x00000000c7fcbf80

Comment: I'd also like to know whether my answer was sufficient. Not only for accepting the answer but @HimanshuDutta might really actually think of something different and if this is the case I'm curious what it is.